# WCF queue and transaction feature

Tags: wcf, queue

Is there any out of the box support for queueing WCF service request and commiting them in a transaction (server side)? E.g.

```
Begin
Insert
Insert
Delete
Edit
Commit
```

The comsumer would start the queue/transaction by calling begin, invoking multiple service requests, and committing by calling commit.

Note that this should only tie to the application layer and not the database.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible.

You should use the Sessions and Transaction Flow features of WCF.

With Session, you can control, in which order your operations have to be called within a session, by marking which operation should start a session and which one should end it.

Transaction Flow would keep the transaction you create in Client side carried over to the server side and will maintain it.

You may refer to [Enabling Transaction Flow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733116.aspx), [WCF Transaction Propagation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163432.aspx), and [Sessions, Instancing and Concurrency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731193.aspx) for more detail.

However, I am not sure how you would untie an application transaction from data layer. It won't make sense to keep an application transaction that wouldn't have control on database transaction.

Comment: Agreed, you do want to flow the transaction all the way to the database because otherwise; you'd need to write code to manually implement the "rollback" logic. Most of the major commercial databases support distributed transaction so that shouldn't be a limitation. Of course, these kinds of transactions will hamper the scalability of the application due to database locking so there is always a tradeoff.

Comment: I was kind of hoping that the client wouldn't have to create a session  client side and just invoke the Begin method server side.

Comment: a phone call and 5 min. later...  I was kind of hoping that the client wouldn't have to create a session  client side and just invoke the Begin method server side. Regarding application vs. database transaction, my concern is the use of ODP.NET to communicate with an oracle database. I would of course use a transaction to commit the service calls, however decoupled from the WCF transaction. I'm not sure how well ODP.NET hooks into WCF. From what I understand my proposed scenario is not viable. Correct?

Comment: Your scenario can be brought as you wish, but it would be a long and complex way to do thing manually. Try out some research in ODP.NET to support your scenario, it may work in your way, who knows. Good luck.